# Parent class variable

Tags: php, oop

Here is my basic example:

```
class Foo {

    public $toy = "car";

    public function run() {
        $this->toy = "train";
        $bar = new Bar();
        $bar->run();
    }   
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function run() {
        echo $this->toy;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->run();
```

For some reason it will always echo car not train. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are creating a **new** `Bar` instance inside `Foo::run`. Changes you make to the `Foo` instance have no effect on the `Bar` instance. They are two **different** instances.
 You can also see it this way: Whenever you instantiate an object from the child class, a new instance of the parent class will be created.

You can make the property [`static`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) though, then it will be shared between all instances:

```
class Foo {

    public static $toy = "car";

    public function run() {
        self::$toy = "train";
        $bar = new Bar();
        $bar->run();
    }   
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function run() {
        echo self::$toy;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without making it static?

Comment: @fire: Not if you want to have two different instances share a value. You *could* do it via third object that is referenced by both instances but whether that is convenient or not depends on the actual context.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo` run creates an object `Bar`, which has `toy`, initialized with `car`. So, the result is `car`, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is "delegation": You create a new instance and call this instead of the parents method. What you are looking for is

```
parent::run();
```

This will call the parents method.